# Setters and Getters

Tags: java

I have a program that uses setters and getters to return food names, barcode numbers, and prices. I have the program split into two files. The Food.java and the FoodClass.java. My problem is that I keep getting compile errors in my FoodClass.java file and I'm struggling to figure out what I need to fix. here is what I have so far for my FoodClass file code and to create a method for food 1 and 2 and other method for food 3 and 4.

the errors I am getting:

C:\Users\xXxFl\Desktop\FoodClass.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                food1.setDescription( "Olives" );
                     ^
  symbol:   method setDescription(String)
  location: variable food1 of type Food

C:\Users\xXxFl\Desktop\FoodClass.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                food2.setDescription( "Duncan Hind Cake Mix" );
                     ^
  symbol:   method setDescription(String)
  location: variable food2 of type Food

C:\Users\xXxFl\Desktop\FoodClass.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                food3.setDescription( "Dog Food" );
                     ^
  symbol:   method setDescription(String)
  location: variable food3 of type Food

C:\Users\xXxFl\Desktop\FoodClass.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
                food4.setDescription( "Cat Food" );
                     ^
  symbol:   method setDescription(String)
  location: variable food4 of type Food

C:\Users\xXxFl\Desktop\FoodClass.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println( food3.getDescription() + "\t\t\t\t\t" + food3.getbarCode + food3.getPrice() );
                                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable getbarCode
  location: variable food3 of type Food

C:\Users\xXxFl\Desktop\FoodClass.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println( food4.getDescription() + "\t\t\t\t\t" + food4.getbarCode + food4.getPrice() );
                                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable getbarCode
  location: variable food4 of type Food
6 errors

```
public class FoodClass
{
public static void main(String [] args )
    {

        //place food1 and food 2 into a String getFoodList method
            Food food1 = new Food();
            Food food2 = new Food();

            food1.setDescription( "Olives" );
            food1.setBarCode("C-234-bb-56");

            food2.setDescription( "Duncan Hind Cake Mix" );
            food2.setBarCode( "23-d-445-66" );

        //place food3 and food4 into a string getFoodPrice method
            Food food3 = new Food();
            Food food4 = new Food();

            food3.setDescription( "Dog Food" );
            food3.setBarCode("34-456-77");
            food3.setPrice( 1.45 );

            food4.setDescription( "Cat Food" );
            food4.setBarCode( "2344-56-2-" );
            food4.setPrice( 2.44 );


        System.out.println( food1.getDescription() + "\t\t\t\t\t" + food1.getbarCode() );
        System.out.println( food2.getDescription() + "\t\t\t\t\t" + food2.getbarCode() );

        System.out.println( food3.getDescription() + "\t\t\t\t\t" + food3.getbarCode + food3.getPrice() );
        System.out.println( food4.getDescription() + "\t\t\t\t\t" + food4.getbarCode + food4.getPrice() );

}
}
```

This is what I have for the Food.java code:

```
public class Food
{


        // Fields
         private String description;
         private String barCode;
         private double price;


    public void setDesrciption( String descriptionGiven ) {
        description = descriptionGiven;
}

    public void setBarCode( String barCodeGiven ) {
        barCode = barCodeGiven;
}

    public void setPrice(double priceGiven ) {
        price = priceGiven;
}


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
}

    public String getbarCode() {
        return barCode;
}

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
}


    public Food( String foodDescription, String foodBarCode) {
        description = foodDescription;
        barCode = foodBarCode;
        price = 0;
}

    public Food( String foodDescription, String foodBarCode, double foodPrice) {
        description = foodDescription;
        barCode = foodBarCode;
        price = foodPrice;
}

    public Food() {                                           
        description = "";
        price = 0;
        barCode = "";

}
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting these errors, and what are they?

Comment: *What* are the compile errors? This is important information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setDesrciption` in `Food` should be `setDescription` and `food3.getbarCode` and `food4.getbarCode` should be `food3.getbarCode()` and `food4.getbarCode()`.

Comment: I still get compile errors: error: cannot find symbol
    food1.setDescription( "Olives" );                                                               cannot find symbol
    food2.setDescription( "Duncan Hind Cake Mix" );

Comment: In `Food` the method is called `setDesrciption`. In `FoodClass` you're calling `setDescription`. As the answer says, rename `setDesrciption` in the `Food` class to `setDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem here is non-uniform naming followed in `FoodClass.java` & `Food.java`.

Either of the below change must get your job resolved.

1. Use `setDescription` instead of `setDesrciption` in `Food.java`.

   > or
2. Use `setDesrciption` instead of `setDescription` in `FoodClass.java`.

Also in `FoodClass.java` `food3.getbarCode` and `food4.getbarCode` must be `food3.getbarCode()` & `food4.getbarCode()` respectively.

Making this changes, does generate the desired output as below.

```
"C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\jbr\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58409:C:\Users\sai\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\work\trial\out\production\trial FoodClass
Olives                  C-234-bb-56
Duncan Hind Cake Mix                    23-d-445-66
Dog Food                    34-456-771.45
Cat Food                    2344-56-2-2.44

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Again to resolve such issues of refactoring, ideally an IDE like Intellij can be your perfect helper.

Comment: That worked thanks. Now im trying to put food 1 and 2 in a method called String getFoodList and then put food 3 and 4 in a method called String getFoodPrice.